# Как перенести ActionBar на все activity?

Tags: actionbar, activity, android

На MainActivity у меня происходит инициализация ActionBar, и появилась необходимость перенести его на другие activity. но переносить код - это не решение. Я пробовал наследовать другие activity от mainactivity, но приложение крашится

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"> 
    <fragment       
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraTargetLat="43.0366700"
        map:cameraTargetLng="44.6677800"
        map:cameraZoom="12"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="false"
        map:uiZoomControls="true"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: в методе MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected (в строке  MainActivity.java:291) не проверяете на null. А оно конечно и упадет.

Comment: Это исправил, но теперь он стал ругаться на xml файл

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.post_req/com.example.post_req.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment.

сам файл в первый пост скинул

Comment: Насколько я понимаю ему не нравится мое объявления фрагмета?

Comment: в моем варианте решения фрагметнов не было.

Comment: Фрагменты были изначально в моем приложении, гугловские карты только на них и работают, вроде как

Answer (score 1):

как вариант главная activity, на ней ActionBar, и франгмент ...  
если наследовать то не от mainactivity а от некого SuperMainactivity в котором только инициализируете  ActionBar, mainactivity в свою очередь так же наследуется от SuperMainactivity

Comment: Сделал таким методом и заработали все активити, кроме той, на которой находится карта. При вызове этой активити приложение крашится. Я мог бы грешить на то, что карты требуют специфического наследования, но они наследуются от обычного activity. Для карт использую google maps api v2

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант, который приходит в голову - сделайте отдельный класс, который умеет инициализировать ActionBar. То есть, он получает ActionBar как параметр (и возможно ещё активити) и выполняет все действия. После этого в каждой активити нужно будет только вставить вызов этого метода этого класса. Метод можно сделать статическим, тогда ещё все упрощается.

разжую:
создаем новый класс, пусть это будет ActionBarUtils

```
import  android.app.*;
class ActionBarUtils {

// инициализирует бар и возвращает true, если все ок.
public static boolean InitActionBar(ActionBar bar) {
    try {
        bar.setTitle("My New title");
        bar.setLogo(....);
    }
    catch(...) { // вставить здесь нужное
      return false;
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

static он для того, что бы не создавать каждый раз.

теперь, в коде onCreate нужной активити пишем

```
if (!ActionBarUtils.InitActionBar(this.getActionBar())) {
    Log.e("can't init bar!");
}
```

А можно код улучшить, и передавать только ссылку на активити. А она пусть найдет.

Этот метод в много раз лучше наследования от активити:

- очень легко применить к любой активити одной строкой.
- иногда, так просто привести к одной общей активити нельзя, а вставить вызов метода - лекго. Даже если активити "не наша".

Comment: и чем же моя идея плохая?

Comment: видимо, для кого-то он слишком непонятный. up

Comment: чуточку расширил:)

Comment: Сделал по такому типу, но теперь при запуске приложение крашится

Comment: к сожалению, телепатически способности у меня не настолько сильные, что бы угадать, где именно оно там свалилось. Стектрейс падения нужно показывать.

Comment: скинул в первый пост